# Why my login page is going to /login.php?login=error after i hit the login button?

Tags: php, mysql, session, passwords

My login page is going to error page after i hit the login button, all of my informations such as Username and Password are correct.

```
} else {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_uid='uid'";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        $resultCheck = msqli_num_rows($result);
        if($resultCheck < 1){
            header("Location: ../login.php?login=error");
            exit();
            } else {
                if($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                    //Dehash pass
                    $hashedPwdCheck = password_verify($pwd, 
                    $row['user_pwd']);
                    if($hashedPwdCheck == false){
                        header("Location: ../login.php?login=error");
                        exit();
                    } elseif ($hashedPwdCheck == true){
                        //Log in
                        $_SESSION[u_id] = $row['user_id'];
                        $_SESSION[u_first] = $row['user_first'];
                        $_SESSION[u_last] = $row['user_last'];
                        $_SESSION[u_email] = $row['user_email'];
                        $_SESSION[u_uid] = $row['user_uid'];
                        header("Location: ../home.php?login=success");
                        exit();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
} else {
    header("Location: ../login.php?login=error");
    exit();
}
```

Comment: How are you setting the hashed password? Is the column in the database at least 60 characters?

Comment: You have to debug your code, do you exit here: if($resultCheck < 1) or here if($hashedPwdCheck == false)?

Comment: `WHERE user_uid='uid'` < seems to me that you're probably wanting to use a variable here, real hard to say.

Comment: Looks like you've got two `else`s, could we see the actual if?

Comment: `$_SESSION[x]` < you're probably getting back errors for non-quoted session arrays, but not checking for errors at all.

Comment: `msqli_num_rows` < major typo. I think the whole question is one big typo.

Comment: @JayBlanchard in the database is set with varchar(256) type, so the max lenght is 256 characters.

Comment: @redreddington This is the actual if
` if(empty($uid) || empty($pwd)){
  header("Location: ../login.php?login=empty");
  exit();
  } else { `

Comment: You have a lot of errors in your php code like @FunkFortyNiner  tells you. So i'll suggest you to debug your code

Comment: I'm voting this as a typographical error because too many have been made.

Comment: @MaxAndrew probably best to update your question to include that part, have you checked that `$pwd` and `$uid` aren't empty because if either of them are you're going to redirect and then your else says redirect as well...

Answer (score -1):

I think the issue is probably the double `else`. Pulling from your comment I'm guessing you code looks like this:

```
if (empty($uid)|| empty($pwd) {
    \\ redirect
} else {
    \\ login logic
} else {
    \\ redirect
}
```

So what you have is either redirect, or redirect. What you probably want to do is lose the last else so you code is just:

```
if (empty($uid)|| empty($pwd) {
    \\ redirect
} else {
    \\ login logic
}
```

As others have pointed out there's a lot of other errors within your code, but this will at least get you out of your redirect problem.